# Where do you listen for emitted event in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, event-handling

Here's the setup:

```
export default Vue.extend({
 name: 'Home',
 computed: {
   ...mapState('user', ['card']),
 },
 created() {
  this.fetchData();
 },
 mounted() {
  this.$once('dataLoaded', () => {
    if (!this.card) {
      this.showWarning();
    }
  });
},
watch: {
  '$route': 'fetchData'
},
methods: {
  async fetchData() {
    await Promise.all([...]);
    this.$emit('dataLoaded');
  },
  showWarning() {
    // Vue global Plugin for creating a banner
    Notify.create();
  }
 }
});
```

I attached the listener in the `mounted` lifecycle but I was wondering if I should do it in `created()`. It seems to work fine in both cases hence my question if there are some best practices or I missed something important here.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it depends on what you to do exactly. If everything you need is ready in created() then its fine, i think

Comment: In general you should use `created` unless you need access to the DOM/refs.

Comment: @HusamIbrahim makes sense! No need for DOM/refs in this case so I guess `created` is the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.
There is no need for `emit` because you are showing us only one component
Just do it like so:

```js
methods: {
  async fetchData() {
    await Promise.all([...]);
    this.myMethod()
  },
  myMethod() {
    if (!this.card) {
      this.showWarning();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I removed a lot of complexity from the component but this is clearly a simpler solution.